# Select hidden and label from enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, enums

project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :details, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :details, allow_destroy: true

end
```

details.rb

```
class Details < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project

  enum question: {
    0: "Question 1...",
    1: "Question 2..."
  }

end
```

details table

```
create_table "details", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "project_id"
    t.integer "question"
    t.string  "answer"
  end
```

project form

```
  = form_for @project do |f|

  ...

  %h3 Questions
  = f.fields_for :details do |d|
    .nested-fields
      .field
        = d.label (question value here)
        = d.hidden_field (question ID here)
        = d.text_field :answer
      %br/

  ...

  .actions
    = f.submit "Submit"
```

Basically my project has a details table that is suppose to store a collection of 5 questions. Those questions are static and will always be the same. What I thought as a solution was to make and enum, and store in the details table the ID of the question and a string with the answer. But now I'm stuck with the form and I would like some help on how can make a form to create and edit the project details. On the form code you can find exactly what I'm trying to do in pseudo-code. I would also be open to a different implementation solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You use `ActiveRecord::Enum` in a wrong way. It is meant to map values to integers:

`enum question: {question1: 1, question2: 2}`,

while you're using it to map integers to values. I'd suggest that you create a simple accessor method:

```
def questions(index)
  ["Question1", "Question2"][index]
end
```

So that you can pick a question like that:

`Detail.questions(n)`

By the way, if you use `Detail` just for holding theses questions, get rid of it and put the above method in `Project`.

Comment: I'm using detail to hold the questions as answers because I want to keep a record from each answers belongs to each question. The accessor method seems like a good approach I will give it a try. Thanks.